# Mint fan control

Tags: linux-mint, hardware, cpu, fan

I've installed Mint 15 on my Alienware m14x and can't figure out one thing. For some reason CPU overheats and fan does not respond to that. It always stays calm and quiet. How exactly I can change that?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this is really a software problem? I'd expect the hardware or the BIOS to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Someone needed to use `fancontrol` over at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) -- it may be of use.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed